# Spring Boot Project in IntelliJ IDEA Showing "Cannot resolve symbol 'persistence'" Error

Tags: java, spring-boot, build.gradle

I'm currently developing a Spring Boot application in IntelliJ IDEA and I have encountered an issue where the IDE is showing "Cannot resolve symbol 'persistence'" error. This error appears whenever I try to import javax.persistence.Entity, javax.persistence.GeneratedValue, javax.persistence.GenerationType, and javax.persistence.Id for my JPA entities.

I have attempted several solutions, such as:

- Rebuilding the project
- Invalidating the caches and restarting IntelliJ IDEA
- Ensuring that my *[build.gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html)* file contains the necessary dependencies.

Here is my build.gradle file:

```
package com.limark.bootcampbackend.domain;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String email;

    // Getters and Setters
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

- 

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.1.2'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.2'
}

group = 'com.limark'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

java {
    sourceCompatibility = '17'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have existing code implemented under the older version of Spring Boot. Probably 2.something. But in the gradle dependency you have the newer version 3.1.2.

There was a massive change between Spring Boot 2 and 3 regarding persistence framework called JPA (Jakarta Persistence Architecture). As a minimum change you should rename all imports `javax.persistence` to `jakarta.persistence`.

For more details you can check the [Hibernate 6.0 Migration Guide](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.0/migration-guide/migration-guide.html).

Comment: this fixed the persistence errors but now when I build the project it gives me these test errors - 
        Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException at AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1770
            Caused by: jakarta.persistence.PersistenceException at AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:421
                Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException at StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:61
                    Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException at ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:693

Comment: In this case please ask a new question and provide more details like the relevant Java code, application.properties or application.yml, application log during startup with full error stacktrace.